# Running a python script on an Android device

Tags: adb, termux, python

I need to control an android app using a python script. Currently, I connect my phone to my laptop and use adb (android debug bridge).

Process:

1. Laptop sends an adb shell command to android to take a snapshot of the screen
2. Android sends the snapshot to my laptop for processing
3. Python/laptop will process the snapshot by analyzing a series of pixels to detect a change in shapes on screen and decide what action to take (tap, swipe, ...)
4. Python/laptop will send an adb shell tap or swipe command to the android device
5. Android will execute the action

The problem is that this process is a little slow and it binds my phone to my laptop.

Is there a way to have the python script live on the android device directly making decisions and taking actions? The closest I have found so far is using Termux, but what library could I use to replace adb? (To analyse the content of the screen, send tap/swipe actions?)

Comment: Your problem is not only to run the script but also to gain the necessary permissions. Termux is an app and everything you execute within is also restricted by these app permissions. Making screen shots of other apps and sending touch commands is disallowed for apps. There are techniques to enable ADB after a reboot via USB so that afterwards apps can make use of ADB on-device. That could be a possible workaround.

Comment: Note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues, so library suggestions are out of scope.